# Can't add image in the editor on mobile

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

There are no advanced features in the mobile editor making it impossible for users to add images in the question.

(Other stuff can be added manually by typing)

Picture showcasing the problem:
[image: no advanced features]

Comment: Just making sure - you're not talking about anything docs-specific?

Comment: @AdamLear Now that you mentioned it, I've just noticed it also applies to other Exchange communities. It's not docs specific.