# Unable to upload photo from iPad

Tags: bug, ipad, uploader, mobile-safari

On the diy site, I'm unable to add an image to a question from an iPad. The imgur dialog is cut off even if I rotate the tablet. The add button on the right of the dialog is not visible.

Comment: Did you try the full site theme?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Scroll down. In the footer, above "2016 Stack Exchange, Inc" and to the right of "contact us", you will see "full site" link. Tap it to be in the full site theme, where you might be able to upload pictures.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good to know. That said, this is still a bug - most visitors aren't going to find that (or ask on meta), and will simply give up.

Comment: Just curious, how did you get to the upload dialog in the mobile theme? As far as I can tell, in the mobile theme there is plain textarea without any formatting options as clearly shown [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270691/cant-add-image-in-the-editor-on-mobile).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I had plain Safari up; I believe I selected the image icon in the question editor.

Comment: Then you should have the full site already since the mobile view doesn't have an editor.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281631/245360