# Could you make it possible to upload pictures from an iPad?

Tags: support, ipad

I apologise, should I have been careless. So far, I see no way to add a picture to my post, other than drag and drop or linking to a site. I own no site and can't drag and drop using the iPad.

Note, that I found this post, but don't consider it duplicate, since to the best of my knowledge I don't have a display problem:

[UNABLE TO UPLOAD PHOTO FROM IPAD - Not really a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277890/unable-to-upload-photo-from-ipad)

Comment: Go to full site, tap the upload image icon in the editor and you can tap there to choose a file from the mobile device pictures.

Comment: Great a million thanks. Do you agree that I should delete this?

Comment: Not yet, maybe I will post it as answer soon for others having this issue.

Comment: In hindsight I think "how could I be so dumb", but there might be others like me...

Comment: I don't think you should have to load the full site if SE supports uploading images from mobile devices.

Comment: Then use the app @keen

Comment: @Keen no it's not. In the mobile site theme (which is the default for mobile devices) there's only plain textarea, without any actions. Click "mobile" in the footer and see for yourself.

Comment: @sha doesn't he mean: *I don't want to go to full site view in order to upload images. Let's be able to do it from the mobile view.*

Comment: @Patrick nope. From the OP comments it's clear he/she simply wasn't aware of the option to go full site on mobile device, and there's already a [popular feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153551/add-an-image-upload-button-to-the-mobile-site) asking to add image upload to mobile web  theme.

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default for mobile browsers is the mobile site theme, which has minimal design, and without the rich editor, meaning no file upload indeed.

However, the footer contains a link to the full site theme:

> [image]

Tap the "full site" link and you'll see the full site on your mobile device. Then you can upload images from your device by tapping the Image icon:

> [image]

As the dialog says, you can tap it (anywhere) to open the device file selection, which is different for every device/OS but you'll be able to choose the desired picture and upload it.

The only catch is the 2 MB limit, which is quite low for most modern devices with HD cameras, so you'll have to shrink the image first if it's bigger. Quick Google search brought [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/image-size/id670766542?mt=8) for iOS (both iPhone and iPad) and [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobilephotoresizer&hl=en_GB) for devices running android OS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on an iPad (or iPhone) you can install the official Stack Exchange app. You can download it from the app store.

It includes a way to post images from your device too, which is very handy if you are on mobile devices which don't like file sharing. The app has a better user experience with typical use of the site and for example file uploading.

(Shadow Wizard mentioned it in his comment it should be possible to use the full site too, but let him post that answer ;))